# What happens when you click on a live video on Instagram?

Tags: instagram

Someone was making a live video, and I clicked on it and it said I joined. Does this mean that the other person saw me through the screen?

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not mean that you actually entered the conversation/interaction mode with the person. It just means that you joined that live broadcast.